# lxc-attach command with redirection

Tags: shell, redirection, proxmox

I'm setting up for a Proxmox 4 server a script that migrates OpenVZ dumps from a Proxmox 3.4. The scripts scp the backups, restores them and so on.

At a time of the process, I'd like to wipe /etc/network/interfaces and setup a new one using "pct set".

My problem is the following: to write default basic configuration into /etc/network/interface, I use lxt-attach. I mistakenly used this:

```
lxc-attach -n 101 -- echo "auto lo" > /etc/network/interfaces
```

You get it: I wiped my host's network config.
So can someone tell me how to execute this command:

```
echo "auto lo" > /etc/network/interfaces
```

in a container using lxc-attach ?

Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Try `lxc-attach -n 101 -- bash -c 'echo "auto lo" > /etc/network/interfaces'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @jordanm said (see comments), this one works:

```
lxc-attach -n 101 -- bash -c 'echo "auto lo" > /etc/network/interfaces'
```